# Выполнить функцию если время компьютера делится на 5 секунд

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Есть 2 браузера открытых на компьютере открытые на одном сайте, нужно одновременно в двух браузерах вызвать функцию ajax(), вопрос в том как сделать так чтобы вызов выполнился в один момент? (Вызов должен быть зациклен) К примеру каждые 5 секунд, я подозреваю что нужно получать время компьютера и если секунды делятся на 5 то ..., по идее это должно работать, можете пожалуйста сказать как это сделать или же другие варианты решения этой проблемы

Comment: Какую конкретно задачу Вы пытаетесь решить? Другими словами, для каких задач необходимо одновременно выполнять AJAX запросы?

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function(){
    var today = new Date().getSeconds();
    if (Math.floor(today / 5) * 5 == today){
        console.log(today);
         // ... тут код Вашего ajax-запроса() ... 
    }
}, 1000);
```